# Qt link library error: "cannot find -lmylib"

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Hi guys I am learning qt5 and trying to make my own share library; I followed most tutorials I can find online but this was a linking error I cannot solve. Here is the file structure:

[image]

I created a subdir project named QTest2 and added one test project "mytest" and the library project "mylib"; then by clicking "Add library" -> "Internal library" on "mytest", the library should be linked to it. Please have a look at the code:

mylib.pro:

```
QT -= gui

TEMPLATE = lib
DEFINES += MYLIB_LIBRARY

CONFIG += c++11

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    mylib.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mylib_global.h \
    mylib.h

# Default rules for deployment.
unix {
    target.path = /usr/lib
}
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

mylib.h:

```
#ifndef MYLIB_H

#define MYLIB_H

#include "mylib_global.h"
#include <QDebug>

class MYLIB_EXPORT Mylib
{
public:
    Mylib();
    int test();
};

#endif // MYLIB_H
```

mylib_global.h:

```
#ifndef MYLIB_GLOBAL_H
#define MYLIB_GLOBAL_H

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#if defined(MYLIB_LIBRARY)
#  define MYLIB_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define MYLIB_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif // MYLIB_GLOBAL_H
```

mylib.cpp:

```
#include "mylib.h"

Mylib::Mylib()
{
}

int Mylib::test()
{
    qDebug()<<"Hello World"<<endl;

    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        sum += i;
    }

    qDebug()<<sum<<endl;

    return sum;
}
```

mytest.pro

```
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../mylib/release/ -lmylib
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../mylib/debug/ -lmylib

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../mylib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../mylib
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

#include "../mylib/mylib_global.h"
#include "../mylib/mylib.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);


    Mylib mylib;

    int result = mylib.test();

    qInfo() << result << endl;

    return a.exec();
}
```

I am pretty sure that I did not miss any step on the tutorial and also tried to rebuild the projects but every time I just got

```
:-1: error: cannot find -lmylib
:-1: error: collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Platform: Qt 5.14, Qt Creator 4.11.0, Windows 10

Any advise would be appreciated. I have been stuck in this for days :(

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to don't use the export/import Macros of Qt. You can export every symbol(class, methods...) without using the Macros. Remove `mylib_global.h`, `MYLIB_EXPORT` from `class MYLIB_EXPORT Mylib`, and `#ifndef MYLIB_H` and `#define MYLIB_H`.

First you have to create the shared library:

```
#library.pro
TARGET = libraryName
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += c++11 warn_off
DESTDIR = $$PWD/lib

INCLUDEPATH += path/to/source
include(path/to/source/source.pri)
```

The source.pri may have the following structure:

```
HEADERS += \
    $$PWD/mylib.h

SOURCE += \
     $$PWD/mylib.cpp
```

Rebuild `library.pro` and the shared library will be created in `DESTDIR`. Then you have to link the library as your are doing in your `mytest.pro`.